# PHP: finding the shortest solution for a recursive function

Tags: php, recursion, optimization

I have tried to solve this problem: you are given two integers(A and B). You need to make an output from A to B(inclusively) in ascending order if A < B and in descending order if B < A. The problem is that it has to be done using a recursive function. I have come up with the following:

```
function showAB($a, $b) {
    if ($a > $b) {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return $a;
        } else {
            return $a . "<br>" . showAB($a - 1, $b);
        }
    } 
    else {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return $a;
        } else {
            return $a . "<br>" . showAB($a + 1, $b);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I was told that the solution to this problem can be done in 2 lines of code or less, so my question is about optimizing the function I already have.

Comment: "optimizing" isn't allways squeesing everything in 2 lines... There is code that can never be reached though (line 4)

Comment: beware of the word "optimizing". When looking at your code now, it's readable and easy to follow logically. An "optimized" solution with fewer lines of code may be a single function that has a single line of code: `return ($a > $b) ? $a."<br>".showAB($a-1, $b) : ($a == $b) ? $a : $a."<br>".showAB($a+1, $b);` I haven't tested this, but this should execute the same as the code above and is only a single line! But it's nowhere near as readable as what you have...

Comment: As @WOUNDEDStevenJones says, optimising often makes code a lot less readable. Here's a pretty simple version though: `return ($a != $b) ? $a . '<br>' . showAB($a + ($a < $b ? 1 : -1), $b) : $a . '<br>';` https://3v4l.org/bba8k

Comment: He has logic in his function what will never run like within his first if statement, `$a` will never `== $b` because if `$a > $b` they are obviously not equal to each other

Answer (score 1):

You can still optimise without making it look ugly, especially removing pointless logic. If you want a 1 liner then refer to the comments otherwise you can remove your else statements and it's still easy to read:

```
function showAB($a, $b) {
    if ($a < $b) {
        return $a . "<br>" . showAB($a + 1, $b);
    }
    if ($a > $b) {
      return $a . "<br>" . showAB($a - 1, $b);
    } 
    return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Golf? You could use the ternary operator `?`..`:` and the 'spaceship' operator `<=>` giving *-1/0/1* for *less than/equal/greater than*

```
function showAB(int $a, int $b) : string
{
  return $a . '<br>' . PHP_EOL . ($a === $b ? '' : showAB($a - ($a<=>$b), $b));
}
```

Comment: I know what `PHP_EOL` does, but I would like to know why you decided to use it and is it necessary or not.